# how to use Jquery UI and Angular JS together

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-scope

I am looking for some angular library which uses all the Jquery UI functionality. I have found some angular codes that provides drag drop. But I want a library that includes drag, drop with scope of angular in just one library. Can anyone suggest me that.

Comment: It's simple enough to write yourself. All you need to do is set up default jquery UI functionality, hook up your angular in the markup, then on the jquery UI events (recieve etc) just set the appropriate properties of your corresponding Angular variables.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Can you show a fiddle of your example of what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You have the [Drag and Drop for AngularJS](http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/) module which is specifically aimed at drag'n'dropping things.

If you are looking for some other UI components, you could start by looking at the [Angular UI project](http://angular-ui.github.io/) modules.

If you are looking for drag'n'dropping and resizing items in a grid, you can look at [angular-gridster](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster).

Comment: Does it support Drag drop and resize.

Comment: If you are looking for drag'n'dropping and resizing items in a grid, you can look at angular-gridster.
I edited.